# What happened to this Git repo and how can I restore sanity to it?

Tags: git, tfs

I returned from a conference and have found a delightful oddity in the master branch of a critical project. A number of files I had committed prior to the conference no longer show up at the head of the master.

### Symptoms

If I look at the history of the directory containing the missing files through either TFS's web interface or the integration in Visual Studio, the last commit to anything in the directory is me adding several of the missing files. There are no subsequent commits removing them.

If I navigate the project through the TFS web interface, my files do not exist in the directory.

If I examine them from the command line with `git log [directory]`, the last commit that comes up is one from back on August 24th, prior to the addition of the missing files. Five commits are missing.

If I execute `git log .` at the top level of the project, these five commit messages *do* appear.

There are two commits to the project that were done by a currently-unavailable coworker while I was gone. They do not touch the same part of the project that the files are missing from. There is a good chance the coworker last pulled from the master after August 24th, but prior to the five subsequent commits.

### Theory

From my limited understanding, I am theorizing that the coworker ran into conflicts when trying to bring his changes in and, rather than resolve them, may have done a `git reset` in order to proceed, but admittedly my knowledge of those realms of git is shaky at best.

### Questions

- Does that fit the symptoms described above?
- Are there things in logs I can look for that would indicate such an action?
- If that is the likely cause, how can I recover the five-or-so commits that appear to have been undone?

Comment: Try running `git reflog` you should see more commits there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short version

1. Yes.
2. Use `--full-history`, and optionally also `-m` and more flags if desired.
3. You may be able to use `git cherry-pick` to re-copy the original commits to new, post-merge commits; or it may be simpler to do some of it manually.  You can use `git show -m` on any given "bad" merge to get diffs against both parents, and then hand-apply dropped changes, or even massage the diffs and use `git apply`.   Or, you can check out the commit just before the bad merge, manually re-do the merge yourself, diff the tree for the "wrong" merge against the tree for the corrected one, and hence come up with a patch that might apply to the commit chain you have now.

#### Long version of point 2

Use `git log --full-history -- <path>` to avoid dropping some commits that touch the given path.  Without `--full-history`, Git tends to discard merges that modify the file from one side only, e.g., that have, on a per-file basis, resolved conflicts using an ours-or-theirs-only strategy.  (This seems like a bug of sorts to me:  Some cases of commit-limiting, as with paths here, probably should *include* some or even all of the merges that combined diff *explicitly discards*.  But that's a philosophical change / "bug", rather than an outright "clearly not correct behavior" bug.)

Add `-m --name-status` to observe modifications in the merge commits themselves.  Add `--merges` as well to observe *only* merges:

```
git log --full-history -m --name-status --merges -- <path>...
```

You may replace `--name-status` with `-p` to have `git log` show diffs.  Or, once you have found suspicious merges (by their hash IDs), use `git show -m <hash>` to view them in detail.

Note that with `-m`, the output from `git log` and `git show` for merges changes a bit:

```
commit <sha1> (from <parentN>)
Merge: <parent1> <parent2>
Author: ...
```

What the `-m` flag does here is to split the merge, for diff purposes, into multiple virtual commits, one for each parent.  The diff is then done against that specific parent.

#### Scenario (or how you got here, or long version of point 1)

All too often, someone runs `git merge` and mis-handles merge conflicts by simply choosing "version on the left" or "version on the right" instead of "mostly from the base, with a little from the left as appropriate, and a little from the right as needed".  The result is that the conflicted file *loses all the changes from one half of the merge*.

Sometimes that *is* the right thing to do, and sometimes it's not.  Git produced a conflict because *at least some* of the changes conflicted.  When some of the changes conflict, it's quite possible that only "column A" or "column B" has the right answer.  But we might have *non*-conflicting changes in the same file, on different lines.

For instance, consider this fragment of a (rather artificial) text file:

```
  #       base             column A           column B

 94:   We show that       We show that       We show that
 95:   2 + 2 = 5.         2 + 2 = 3.         2 + 2 = 4.
 96:
 97:
 98:
 99:
100:
101:
102:   This moth proof... This math proof... This moth proof...
```

The "base" version has two errors, one being the claim that `2 + 2 = 5` and the other calling it a `moth proof`.

The version on one branch, in "column A", tries to correct it: 2+2 is not five, and it's a math (or ["maths"](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/math-or-maths/)) proof, not a moth proof.

The version on the other branch, "column B", *does* correct it—but the author of that version missed the bug on line 102.

The correct merge strategy, in this case, is to take line 95 from the second changed version, and line 102 from the first changed version.  Some merge tools make this easy to do correctly—I myself use `vim` on a file with merge conflict markers with `merge.conflictstyle = diff3`, and hence don't even have to *see* line 102 where there was no conflict—and some merge tools try to show you a global-ish view, making it far too easy to eyeball this and say "oh, just use the second parent" (column B).

In short, your theory is probably correct (although `git reset` was probably not the culprit).  To find out for sure, though, you would have to observe the same person re-doing that same merge—assuming he or she has not yet learned to do the merge correctly!

#### Long version of point 3

This works best, I think, with a drawing of some of the commit graph.  You can get this from various tools, including `git log --graph` (optionally with `--oneline` and flags like `--decorate`), and from visualizers like `gitk`.  They tend to present the graph vertically, with newer commits towards the top.  I like to draw them horizontally, with newer commits towards the right, for textual reasons.

Let's say that the graph currently looks something like this:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--E--M--o--o--F   <-- branch
         \            /
          A--B--C--D-´   <-- topic [label may no longer exist]
```

Here, `*` is the merge base for faulty merge `M`.  At the time someone broke things, the tip of the more main `branch` was commit `E` and the tip of the `topic` branch was commit `D`.  The person who did the merge was on branch `branch`, and things looked like this:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--E   <-- branch
         \
          A--B--C--D    <-- topic
```

They ran `git merge branch`, or perhaps did the equivalent from some GUI that led them down the faulty-merge-garden-path.  This produced merge conflicts, which they resolved inappropriately and committed.

You can re-do the entire merge.  Simply check out commit `E` by ID, and/or give it a branch name.  Using `git checkout -b` we can do both at once:

```
git checkout -b remerge <id-of-E>
```

(Or, you can do this in "detached HEAD" mode, which is what I would do for a quick one-off test.  You can always give the detached HEAD a name with `git checkout -b` later.)

Now that commit `E` is current, simply re-run the merge:

```
git merge <id-of-D>
```

Git will perform the same merge actions it would have "back then", since it's merging the same commit into the same commit, starting from the same graph.  (Note: if you have `git rerere` enabled, you may want to temporarily *dis*able it here, especially if you are the one who made the faulty merge. :-) )

If you now resolve the conflicts (correctly this time) and commit the result, you'll get a new merge `M2`:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--E--M--o--...   <-- branch
         \           \/
          A--B--C--D-´\
                    \  \
                     `--M2   <-- remerge
```

You can now compare `M` vs `M2`:

```
git diff <id-of-M> HEAD
```

to see what is needed to change `M` into `M2`.

#### There are many options here

Whether or not you make `M2`, you can:

- Look at commits `A--B--C--D`, and if you just need some or all of them, use `git cherry-pick` to copy them to where you are now:

  ```
  ...--o--*--o--o--o--E--M--o--o--F--A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- branch
           \            /
            A--B--C--D-´
  ```

  Here `A'`, `B'`, `C'`, and `D'` are cherry-picked copies of `A` through `D`.
- Try `git apply`-ing the diff between `M` and `M2` atop `F`:

  ```
  ...--o--*--o--o--o--E--M--o--o--F--G   <-- branch
           \            /
            A--B--C--D-´
  ```

  (save the `git diff` output in a file, or re-run the `git diff` and pipe to `git apply`).
- You can even merge `M2` in to `branch` now (although this will likely be quite messy: the merge base of commits `F` and `M2` is a virtual merge of `D` and `E`, which is a bad situation since we're presupposing conflicts here in the first place!), or cherry-pick `M2` against one of its first parent `E`.

Depending on the situation, I would probably go with cherry-picking `A--B--C--D` if there are not too many, or even copying them into a new topic branch and merging that; or just `git apply`-ing the `M`-vs-`M2` diff.

#### Using rebase to copy a topic branch to redo the merge another way

The "copy to a new topic branch" method probably deserves its own little description here, though, since `git rebase` is the command that does this.  Here is how to use `git rebase` to copy `topic` to `retopic`.  Let's assume we start with this:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--E--M--o--o--F   <-- branch
         \            /
          A--B--C--D-´   <-- topic
```

First, we need a branch named `retopic`:

```
git checkout -b retopic topic
```

(If the name `topic` is gone, use the ID of commit `D`.)  Now we have:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--E--M--o--o--F   <-- branch
         \            /
          A--B--C--D-´   <-- topic, HEAD -> retopic
```

Now simply run `git rebase --onto branch <id-of-E>`.  If the ID of `E` is not handy but the ID of commit `A` is, use `<id-of-A>^` (note the hat suffix) to produce the ID of commit `*`.  All we're doing here is directing `git rebase` to copy commits ending at `D` (where `retopic` points), and starting from commit `A` (by excluding commits `*` and earlier, which are reachable from commit `E`).

Resolve conflicts as they occur—you may want to enable `git rerere` before you even begin the rebase—and when you are done you have this:

```
                                  A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- HEAD -> retopic
                                 /
...--o--*--o--o--o--E--M--o--o--F   <-- branch
         \            /
          A--B--C--D-´   <-- topic
```

You can now `git checkout branch` and `git merge --no-ff retopic` to make a *new* merge `M2` from the rebase-copied commits.  (Note: some or all of `A'` through `D'` may drop out entirely during the copying, depending on what was retained in faulty merge `M`.)